# Returning a custom value rather than {} when Solve finds no solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
n /. 
  Solve[
    {c == 1/2 (-2 + 3 n^2) (-1 + 3 n^2) (1 - 3 n + 3 n^3), 
     n ∈ PositiveIntegers}, 
    n
  ][[1]]
```

This restricts the number $n$ such that the equation is solved in the natural numbers because $c\in\mathbb{N}$. However when no solution is found the code gives an error message:

> Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.
> ReplaceAll::reps: {{}[[1]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

How can I write code that gives $n$ when it exists, and it gives $0$ if no solution exists?

For example, when $c = 1045$, we see that $n=2\in\mathbb{N}$ so the code gives $2$, but when $c=1046$ there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that solves the equation so the code should give $0$.

Comment: You are perhaps phrasing this incorrectly. `Solve` of course should not return a solution of 0 when the correct thing is an empty set. So you might write a code snippet that converts a solution set of `{}` to 0 before doing the substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

soln[c_Integer] := Module[{sol = Solve[{
      c == 1/2 (-2 + 3 n^2) (-1 + 3 n^2) (1 - 3 n + 3 n^3),
      n ∈ PositiveIntegers}, n]},
  If[Length[sol] > 0, n /. sol[[1]], 0]]

soln /@ {1045, 1046}

(* {2, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using [`Check`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html), which checks for messages and allows an alternate return value if any messages have been generated.

```
solver =
  Quiet @
     Check[
       Solve[
         # == 1/2 (-2 + 3 n^2) (-1 + 3 n^2) (1 - 3 n + 3 n^3),
         n, PositiveIntegers][[1, 1, 2]],
       0] &;
```

Then the first 2000 positive integers can be searched for a solution with

```
solver /@ Range[2000] // SparseArray
```

[image: result]

However, what I don't understand is why you don't go about solving your problem by inverting it.

```
solns =
  With[{nMax = 10},
    Table[{1/2 (-2 + 3 n^2) (-1 + 3 n^2) (1 - 3 n + 3 n^3), n}, {n, nMax}]];
TableForm[solns, TableHeadings -> {None, {"c", "n"}}]
```

[image: result]

Much easier and very much faster.